# How to implement Collapsible side bar in Angular2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular, toggle

I'm learning angular2 and looking to implement a collapsible sidebar, similar to https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html, in Angular 2?  I tried looking up examples but couldn't find any. Can you provide examples or documentation for it?

Comment: I wrote something similar in angular 1.x, hope this can help,https://github.com/postor/ng-collpase, example:http://plnkr.co/edit/QFp379dEFQhKGRxmJz7p?p=preview

Comment: @shaswa did you find a solution finally ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use ng2-bootstrap:

<s>https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/accordion</s>

You can also check in the source code how it's implemented:

<s>https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/tree/development/components/accordion</s>

Comment: The example collapses the whole div/sidebar though. I still want to be able to show the menu icon when collapsed like in https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to do it with Bootstrap, you can do it with [Bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

http://codepen.io/zurfyx/pen/ygaGyb

The idea behind this solution is the following:

Have your **collapsible content** inside a specific class, we called it `collapseMenu`. We also need a class that will indicate whether it is hidden or not. Bootstrap already provides it for us `collapse`.

```
<li>Icon <span class="collapse collapseMenu">Home</span></li>
```

Next we need the **toggler**, the hamburger icon that is. It requires a `data-toggle` to indicate the class that it has to toggle on each click and a `data-target` to know the element(s) that has to target, `collapseMenu`.

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseMenu">Hamburger icon</button>
```

The **CSS** part is not a big deal, and you can do it in various ways. I like the CSS3 [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) approach.

Our page (specifically `.container`), will be a flex with direction row.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Then we'll set the right panel to take as much space as it can, so as when the content is toggled, it shrinks:

```
.main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

---

Complete working version:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-panel">
        <ul>
            <li>Icon <span class="collapse collapseMenu">Home</span></li>
            <li>Icon <span class="collapse collapseMenu">Contact</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseMenu">Hamburger icon</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
    display: block;
}

.collapse.in {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 0;
}

.left-panel {
    background-color: grey;
}

.main {
    background-color: black;
    flex: 1;
}
```