# Implementing a collapsible sidebar in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Am converting A html jquery adminlte dashboard to angular2

Previously when using Jquery the sidebar is hidden and shown using `toggle()`

Now how do i do it in angular2

Am using [Almaaseed admin lte template](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html)

This is what i have tried

I have a dashboard component

```
export class DashboardComponent {
 public constructor(private titleService: Title) {

  }

  onSidenavigation(){
    //i would like to perform toggle
  }
```

This is the button that toggles display

```
<a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" (click)="onSidenavigation()" 
  role="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </a>
```

I have checked on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110089/how-to-implement-collapsible-side-bar-in-angular2)  but has no answer yet

Answer (score 0):

You could make a CSS max-height transition. Use a template property to set the css class that animates the height. Toggle the property that sets the class on clicking the button. Something like this...

```
<div id="sidebar" [class.sidebar-is-visible]="sidebarIsVisible">

<button (click)="sidebarIsVisible = !sidebarIsVisible">

#sidebar {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar.sidebar-is-visible {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```